# Excluding an address from fees in _transfer function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, wallets

I intend to exclude the deployer of the contract from paying a 9% fee, which is placed on every transfer. I tried to do this by adding a if statement to *_transfer* that checks if the sender has the same address as the deployer. However, after testing this on pancakeswap the deployer is still paying a fee.

```
contract token is ERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint feePercentage = 9;
    address public deployer;

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("token", "tkn") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
        deployer = msg.sender;
    }

    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override {
        if (sender != deployer) {
            uint256 FeeAmount = amount.mul(feePercentage) / 100;
            super._transfer(sender, deployer, FeeAmount);
            amount -= FeeAmount;
        }
        super._transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt variable called owner(), that is used for just such a thing. (Because your contract is Ownable.)

So your code would look something like this

```
contract token is ERC20, Ownable {
        using SafeMath for uint256;
        uint taxPercentage = 9;
    
        constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("token", "tkn") {
            _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
        }
    
        function _transfer(
            address sender,
            address recipient,
            uint256 amount
        ) internal override {
            if (sender != owner()) {
                uint256 FeeAmount = amount.mul(taxPercentage) / 100;
                super._transfer(sender, owner(), FeeAmount); //Maybe this should be recipient instead owner/deployer?? I added owner based on your code
                amount -= FeeAmount;
            }
            super._transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this would work as I may renounce ownership of the contract in the future. Is there another work around?

Comment: You could create a function SetDeployer(address _address) {
deployer=_address;
}

That way you can be sure as to who the deployer is.
The issue in your code is that msg.sender is called by the contract. So it sets the contract address as the deployer. (Try to print out deplyoer variable to debug it).

Comment: And for safety reasons you could write the function like this: SetDeployer(address _address) public onlyOwner { deployer=_address; }

This way only you (the owner will be able to call the function) and once you renounce the ownership nobody will.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer:

Instead of checking if the sender == deployer, I opted to check if the recipient == deployer and it is working as intended (seemingly). I assume it is due to how exchanges handle transfers during a swap?

Comment: Usually, the Transfer function only has a recipient, and the amount --->

super.transfer(recipient, amount); But it would seem logical to verify the sender if you do not wish to charge him a fee.